# How to merge data from 2 tables with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I have 2 tables set up something like below, what MySQL querys do I need to use to return  assoc arrays of each entry along with it's associated fields? I've tried various JOINs but they all return a result for every item in the second table. Ultimately I want a parent array with one child array for each item in the first table. Each child array would contain the name from table A along with all the fields that belong to it from table B where B.entryID = A.ID.

```
A
ID    |Name    |Created
1     Jeff     2013-20-12
2     Bob      2011-23-14

B
ID    |Value   |FieldID    |entryID
1     U.S      1            1
2     91725    2            1
3     China    1            2
```

DESIRED STRUCTURE

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jeff
            [1] => U.S
            [2] => 91420
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bob
            [1] => China
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: can you please post your code/query? so it will be helpful to debug it.

Comment: `I've tried various JOINs` which `joins`?

Comment: Yeah basically like the answer below which gave me too many results so I tried using RIGHT JOIN or INNER JOIN aswell but still get too many results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Value from A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID=B.entryID
```

Comment: Yes this was the first 'join' I tried but it returns an array for every entry in table B. Each array contains the 'Value' and the 'Name' from table A. So If I have 3 entries in table A, I only want 3 arrays returned, but I'm getting one for each field instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are a few ways to do this...

### Method 1

If you take out the *array* bit and were to handle your data more appropriately the *right* way to do this would be:

```
SELECT `A`.`ID`, `A`.`Name`, `B`.`Value`
FROM A
INNER JOIN
  `B` ON `A`.`ID` = `B`.`entryID`
ORDER BY `A`.`ID`, `B`.`Value`
```

This will return results like:

```
array(
  0 => array(ID=>1, Name=>'Jeff', Value=>'U.S'),
  1 => array(ID=>1, Name=>'Jeff', Value=>'91725'),
  2 => array(ID=>2, Name=>'Bob',  Value=>'China')
)
```

Which you would iterate through like so (you could modify this to create the array structure you're after as opposed to echoing to a string...):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);//Make your db connection
$query  = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT `A`.`ID`, `A`.`Name`, `B`.`Value`
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN
      `B` ON `A`.`ID` = `B`.`entryID`
    ORDER BY `A`.`ID`, `B`.`Value`
    ");
$newArr = array();
$lastID = '';
if($query->num_rows){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        if($lastID == $row['ID']){
            end($newArr);
            $key = key($newArr);
            $newArr[$key][] = $row['Value'];
        }
        else{
            $newArr[] = array($row['Name'], $row['Value']);
        }
        $lastID = $row['ID'];
    }
}
var_export($newArr);

/**
Output:

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Jeff',
    1 => 'U.S.',
    2 => '91275',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Bob',
    1 => 'China',
  ),
)

*/
```

---

### Method 2

If you *really* want/need to output as an array from the `SQL query` then I'd suggest something like the following:

```
SELECT
    A.ID, A.Name,
    CONCAT(
      '[',
      GROUP_CONCAT('"', B.Value, '"'),
      ']'
    ) as Values
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.entryID = A.ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Which would output `Values` as `json`:

```
array(
    0=>arryay(ID=>1, Name=> 'Jeff', Values='["U.S.", "91725"]'),
    1=>arryay(ID=>1, Name=> 'Bob',  Values='["China"]')
)
```

and you would need to run `json_decode` on the `Values` each time you accessed the record in `php`. Something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);//Make your db connection
$query  = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT
        A.ID, A.Name,
        CONCAT(
          '[',
          GROUP_CONCAT('"', B.Value, '"'),
          ']'
        ) as Values
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON B.entryID = A.ID
    GROUP BY A.ID
    ");

$newArr = array();
if($query->num_rows){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $newArr[] = array($row['Name']);
        end($newArr);
        $key = key($newArr);
        $fieldData = json_decode($row['Values']);
        foreach($fieldData as $value){
            $newArr[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }
}
var_export($newArr);


/**
Output:

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Jeff',
    1 => 'U.S.',
    2 => '91275',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Bob',
    1 => 'China',
  ),
)

*/
```

**NOTE:** I suggest that you don't do it this way... As it could lead to all sorts of bugs if your data isn't stored in a way that can allow for this (e.g. if you haven't encoded/escaped `"`). You might also run into problems if there is a large amount of data being pulled from `B`...

Comment: Ok that looks more like it. The whole array structure will be JSON encoded. How would that affect the Values being JSON encoded already?\

Comment: Sorry, you mean that you want to `json_encode` the output of the query?

Comment: yes. Also, I need to keep the "field_id" thats associated with each "value" so I can look up the field names later.

Comment: Ok to be a bit clearer I've added an example of the desired array structure. It seems so simple but I can't figure a method to get there. The array keys need to be the 'field_id's from table b so i can look them up later. We can assume [0] is always 'name' from table A.

Comment: Okay, I updated both _Methods_ above and displayed their output from the queries... Depending on whether your `FieldID` will always start from `1` and work up this, above, will be fine (Just make sure to `ORDER BY FieldID`.. If that's not the case then a small tweak will be in order! Anyway, let me know how you get on.